# Program in c# stopped working after change of router

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, ip

I tried everything I could, but nothing works. My IP address 3 first digits changed from 192.168.1 to 192.168.0. The program has to accept data from address 192.168.0.255  then in reaction, it has to open a window and play video from a folder and is set to listen to every IP address there shouldn't be a problem before the change of router everything worked as expected.
For sending data I use my own android app I tested that app with Wireshark everything works as it should.
The window doesn't open everything works, but it seems that the socket just doesn't get any data.=>condition checking for available data socket available>0 returns false.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace SysConf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 


    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       
        Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        Timer timer1;
     
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;


        Encoding coding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2");
        int ByteC;
        Byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        EndPoint rE = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2200);
        int order = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Clipboard.SetText(GetLocalIPAddress());
        }

        public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {

                    if (ip.ToString().Split('.')[0] == "192")
                    {
                        return ip.ToString();
                    }

                }
            }
            throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
        }

       


        

        private void MainWindow1_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MainWindow1.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) { MainWindow1.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None; }
            else { MainWindow1.WindowStyle= WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow; }
         
        }

        private void MainWindow1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.F11)
            {
                if (MainWindow1.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                {
                    MainWindow1.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    MainWindow1.Topmost = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    MainWindow1.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    MainWindow1.Topmost = true;

                }
            }
        }

        private void MainWindow1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            //   win = (SysConf.MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
           // MainWindow1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;


            MainWindow1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            if (GetLocalIPAddress() != "No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!")
            {
                sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPAddress()), 2200));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Internet connection!");
            }
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          

            if (player1.Position == player1.NaturalDuration & MainWindow1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                MainWindow1.Topmost = false;
                MainWindow1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }


            Task.Run(() =>
            {
              

                if (sck.Available > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data arrived");
                   
                    ByteC = sck.ReceiveFrom(bytes, ref rE);
                    order = 1;
                   

                }
             

            });
            

            

            if (order == 1)
            {
                this.Close();
                String cmd = coding.GetString(bytes);
                   
                    MainWindow1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    MainWindow1.Topmost = true;
                    player1.Source = new Uri("Resources/" + (cmd.Substring(0,12)).Split('_')[1] + ".mp4", UriKind.Relative); //+ (@"\Resources\" ), UriKind.Relative);
                    player1.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    MainWindow1.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    player1.Play();
                    
                


                order = 0;

                bytes = null;
                bytes = new byte[9024];
                cmd = "";
            }


            
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            //win.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void player1_BufferingEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to start by checking if you have a route to the IP address(s) from cmd.exe >PING IP.  Most likely it is a mask issue on a adapter.  You can use from cmd.exe >IPConfig/all to check the masks.  A router will normally block Multicast addresses that are used for router discovery.  So either a router mask is different or the setting in the old router was allowing multicast to pass.  I don't think the application is the issue.  You also could be using an intelligent  router that doesn't allow more than one source IP address to be used.

Comment: Try not to use multicast, and see if it works.If it works the comment from jdweng is correct.

Comment: @jdweng In the Wireshark, there's an arp request but no real sending begins. Which is very strange cause it didn't behave like this before. I've tried to fix it before when data was still being sent, but the router seemingly stopped them from reaching their destination. I am really considering changing the router right now...

Comment: You may not have a route.  Try both by name and IP. Some times you have a route in one direction and not reverse.   So try ping in both dirrections.  Routers can be blocking port numbers.  You could be using routing with masks and mask is bad or using a DNS server to get route by machine name.  You have to find where the issue is by using ping on different machine to isolate where the route is breaking.  You could take a laptop with a sniffer and move to different parts of the network to find where th ARP is stopping.  Also use from cmd.exe >ARP -a to get arp table on different machines.

Comment: It suddenly started working again don't know why. Maybe software error got patched in update.